# how to read last data of column using datareader in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

I have one database and I want to get last value of column, and each time value will be updated after insertion 
here is sample database,

```
ID | Customer_Name |new_Total | Total
--------------------------------------
1  |     Mahesh    |   100    |  200
2  |     Mahesh    |   400    |  600 (200+400)
3  |     mahesh    |   100    |  700 (600+100)
```

Comment: do you mean any last updated value or last (max) value of a column? Please clarify.

Comment: You can easy use Sql command and it automatically updated for last column. do you need that command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i am getting you right you need to get last value of column i assume Total column.Here is you can read last value from database.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ToString()))
{
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Top 1 Total from tablename order by total desc", con);
 SqlDataReader rdr;
 con.Open();
 rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
 while (rdr.Read())
  {
   int total;
   int.TryParse(rdr["Total"].ToString(), out total);
  }

}
```

You will get value in total variable and you can use it.